# ADO.Net - Why isn't the insert happening?

Tags: c#, ado.net, .net-4.0, sql-server-express

I went through MSDN pages to learn ADO.Net using Commands. I am able to read using the sample code posted there.

But when I tried to use the modification code below, the insert is not happening. I am not ale to figure out why. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
string connectionString = "A_VALID_CONNECTION_STRING";
string commandText = 
"INSERT INTO Contacts (FullName, Mobile) VALUES ('Pierce Brosnan', '1800-007')";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);          

try
{
  connection.Open();
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
  Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteNonQuery());
  connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

**Edit**

- No exception is thrown.
- The ExecuteNonQuery() which is supposed to return the no. of rows affected is returning `1`.
- Environment: Visual C# 2010 Express | SQL Server 2008 Express | Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit.

**Update**

1. Previously I was using a MDF file present in the project. It was, I guess, automatically attached to the SQL server instance each time the project ran. This is when I had the problem. The connection string had some info about attaching a database file.
2. I removed the SQL Server 2008 Express that I installed along with Visual C# 2010 Express. Also removed the MDF file from the project.
3. I Separately downloaded and installed SQL Server 2008 Express along with Management Studio Express.
4. Created a new database in management studio.
5. Used a different type of connection string to use the database in the server.

Now INSERT is working!

**P.S. I guess I should have mentioned that I had an attach database file scenario. Really sorry for that.**

Comment: No. No exception is thrown (or printed). The Console.WriteLine prints `1`. But when I see the database table, nothing is inserted. I am viewing the data using the database explorer in C# 2010 Express IDE.

Comment: That's really strange. Your code looks fine and if `1` is printed it means that one row was inserted.

Comment: Could it be that the Database Explorer is not showing the updated data? Is it limited in some way because it is in Express edition?

Comment: Try sending another query like `select count(*) from contacts`.

Comment: Is the query running inside a transaction that you are not completing?

Comment: Do the values get inserted when you run the SQL query in Mgmt Studio?? Could there be a trigger or a "silently" failing unique constraint or something on that table??

Comment: @marc_s The first column is ID which is auto increment identity. I didn't include that field, thinking that it will be inserted automatically. Will that be a problem? Also, I am just installing management studio to check that out.

Comment: @Noon The code I have posted is everything there is inside the Main function in the console application. I have not knowingly begun any transaction. Is there anything else that could be going on without me knowing?

Comment: @Senthil: No, a transaction won't be made without you doing it specifically. So then, we can only conclude that you are probably inserting it into a different DB than you are checking, or something of that nature. Can you write a stand-alone program that has the same error (and post it here, if so)?

Comment: @Senthil: the IDENTITY field will be populated automatically, that's most certainly not the problem. I'm just wondering if there are any other constraints (e.g. UNIQUE constraints) on the table, possibly on the "FullName"? If there is, it could totally be that the insert will not happen, if an entry for "Pierce Brosnan" already exists, and that failure could be "silent" (e.g. no exception - the data just doesn't get inserted).

Comment: @marc_c: Yeah, but if there was a unique constraint an exception would be thrown and `1` wouldn't be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suspicion is that you had the following scenario:

- `Database.mdf` file was present in the project with the table structure created in it
- Your connection string looked something like this `Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=database.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;`, i.e. loading the database in the connection string.

What was happening was, when you built/ran your project, your application was compiled and the `database.mdf` file was copied along with it to `ApplicationProjectFolder\bin\Debug`, so that when the application was run, the file `database.mdf` was present. This means that everytime you ran your project, the "empty" `database.mdf` file was copied from `ApplicationProjectFolder\database.mdf` to `ApplicationProjectFolder\bin\Debug\database.mdf`, hence the data "disappearing". Also, the file `database.mdf` probably had "Copy Always" set on its properties in the project.

So, the "INSERT" was working, it was just being "reset" everytime you ran your application.

Comment: Where were you for the last half day? :P Thanks a lot for explaining WHY things started working now! :) As I said, if I had mentioned the scenario completely, I could have gotten the answer earlier :|.. and +1

Comment: @Senthil, not a problem. I've had the same happen to me before, admittedly with a Sql Server Ce database but the principal still stands. As soon as I saw your question I knew what was happening =) PS - Any chance of an upvote on the answer as well as accepted? ;-)

Comment: Ha, isn't it written in the Etiquette Bylaws that you aren't supposed to ask for up-votes?  Besides, how do you expect to earn the Tenacious badge then? (+1)

Comment: @JohnB, probably, but by-laws are the most fun to break ;-)